# How to run build pack without time out using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to push my first site to Heroku, but everything keeps timing out and I'm not to sure why. I don't have a bunch of PDFs which would cause it to time out, so I'm scratching my head.

Here is the error I receive just before it fails:

```
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
       I, [2019-07-02T19:46:47.794669 #1507]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_cabc1b6e8756bc1d1d3a5bd1884ae5fc/public/assets/deli3-397a9ad3da4bc5ec1fba4e10d9e3907174bd0ffe42493e732d6fb61d7f7002d5.png
       I, [2019-07-02T19:46:47.797500 #1507]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_cabc1b6e8756bc1d1d3a5bd1884ae5fc/public/assets/food/food-726680522246b17f86a014fae70f1450435edc64798f8262315c23ccf6fa5744.png
       I, [2019-07-02T19:46:47.799838 #1507]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_cabc1b6e8756bc1d1d3a5bd1884ae5fc/public/assets/food/frying-pan-af3f7e894cee377789f12f96b9f0ab120e8af6aba0cf03b6f8c021f5dadfc704.png
       I, [2019-07-02T19:46:47.802089 #1507]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_cabc1b6e8756bc1d1d3a5bd1884ae5fc/public/assets/food/package-ec6088618de7d2829802bdc57b1ba0de3562ebf11d2ee2588af3432992c254a2.png
       I, [2019-07-02T19:46:50.262020 #1507]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_cabc1b6e8756bc1d1d3a5bd1884ae5fc/public/assets/application-867e786874a7ad085e8e8e6fa4fcdda94aa82c482156efe5a12c59dd8e564d3e.js
       I, [2019-07-02T19:46:50.262656 #1507]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_cabc1b6e8756bc1d1d3a5bd1884ae5fc/public/assets/application-867e786874a7ad085e8e8e6fa4fcdda94aa82c482156efe5a12c59dd8e564d3e.js.gz
-----> Timed out running buildpack Ruby
 !     Timed out compiling app (18 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit
```

I think this is because the precompile is taking too long because of my SCSS files with `@import`. On my local drive I ran this command which has been running/hanging for 20 minutes so far.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
yarn install v1.16.0
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.04s.
```

Comment: What led to your comment about `@import`? Is there more context there?

Comment: I read online regarding similar questions it could be the reason why. I just realised it will precompile my pngs and js files, but none of my css files

Comment: Can you confirm which buildpacks you have setup on your app? And the order they appear in?

Comment: so when I removing my application.css file it work, any ideas why my application.css file is stopping assets: precompile work on production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone runs into the same problem, I have found the issue - my CSS files had custom written CSS-Grid, and some of these values were causing `$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` to hang. I resolved by deleting the CSS-Grid layouts inside the .css file